# How to check if a string contains a particular string using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class

```
public class IgonoreValues
{
    internal static List<string> IgonoreValuesList = new List<string>
    {
       "Merge: ","# Conflicts:"
    };
}
```

it has a list of strings.

Now I have a String ChangeSetInfo it contains

```
    commit 1084b2a815b47fb03632e5bc32a0468ceb1d4bf5
Author: shw<shw@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 23 09:36:34 2021 +0530

    Manager Merge: 

A   Manager/EventCollectionManager.cs
A   Manager/EventCollectionTimer.cs
A   Manager/EventManager.cs
A   Manager/GitManager.cs
```

I want to execute a linq command line for `if (!ChangeSetInfo.Contains("Merge: ") || !ChangeSetInfo.Contains("# Conflicts:"))`

can any one tell me a way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `ChangeSetInfos.All(changeSetInfo => !IgonoreValues. IgonoreValuesList.Contains(changeSetInfo)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this `if(!IgonoreValues.IgonoreValuesList.Any(o => ChangeSetInfo.Contains(o)))`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to check if the string contains any of those ignore-strings. Then use `Any`:

```
if (!IgonoreValues.IgonoreValuesList.Any(ChangeSetInfo.Contains))
{
   // ...
}
```

the case insensitive variant:

```
if (!IgonoreValues.IgonoreValuesList.Any(iv => ChangeSetInfo.Contains(iv, StringComparsion.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
   // ...
}
```